# Visual Studio 2022 intellisense includePath errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, include-path, unreal-engine5

when using the intellisense prompt of VS2022 to automatically include the header file in the code in the Cpp file, the following error always occurs

```
#include "../Config/UGConfigManager.h"
```

Is there any way to replace the path "../" with a full path? Like this:

```
#include "Game/Config/UGConfigManager.h"
```

[image]

EDIT:
In UE5, you need to change NMake's *IncludeSearchPath* instead of *VC++ Directories* in Properties -> NMake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an include path to the "Game" folder.

To set an include path you now must right-click a project and go to:

```
Properties -> VC++ Directories -> General -> Include Directories
```

Then add the include directory like so:

```
C:/foobar/Game
```

First try using an absolute path. And if that works you will want to use a [Macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170). Macros allow users to define paths without being specific to their own computer (So other people can use it).

Perhaps what you need is `$(ProjectDir)` but I can't tell since I don't know where "Game" is relative to your project files.

But as an example:

```
$(ProjectDir)/Game
```

It's worth pointing out that what you are doing is interacting with the compiler option `/I` on the `MSVC compiler`. Visual Studio is just a gui abstracting it away for you.

Here are the docs on [/I (Additional include directories)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did as you said, but the result is still the same. I actually did this before asking the question.It may be due to the difference between the code structure of Unreal Engine and the general C++ project.